# HTML no me reconoce el CSS

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

tengo un problema que me esta volviendo loca...

Estoy armando un emailing con un CSS linkeado, y el html me esta reconociendo solo algunos de los codigos css. En el dreamweaver lo veo correcto! pero en cuanto lo subo al ftp se rompe.

Esta subido aca:

http://donidrault.com.ar/nucleo/AOTCABA/emailing.html

alguien sabe que puede ser?

saludos

Comment: Edita tu pregunta colocando el fragmento de código de como lo estas llamando para que se te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Por lo visto el css esta bien referenciado, lo que no se es cual propiedad no esta cargando bien.

Comment: si es para email todo estilo tiene que estar dentro del html, algunos lectores de mail como outlook tienen caprichos adicionales. imágenes tienen que ser insertadas con ruta completa. para probar si un email se va a ver bien, copia el archivo .html (sólo el html, no css, no imágenes) y abrilo en otra computadora con acceso a internet

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza esto:

```
// Ruta Relativa
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Por esto:

```
// Ruta Absoluta
<link href="http://donidrault.com.ar/nucleo/AOTCABA/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

También podrías utilizar estilos en línea y prescindir de las hojas de estilo *(Recomendado para emailing)*

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://donidrault.com.ar/nucleo/AOTCABA/img/logo_superior.png); height: 300px; background: no-repeat; width: 100%;">
```

Comment: ya lo eh probado y no funciona...

Comment: El problema es que toma algunas cosas del css y otras no, asi que el problema no es que no encuentra el archivo css enlazado... =S

Comment: ¿Ya probaste con la sugerencia de agregar el estilo directo en las etiquetas, cómo lo indico en la respuesta actualizada?

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que esto puede pasar por dos cosas:

1: Problemas con la cache del navegador

2: Lei que estas haciendo un emailing, pues veras, al enviar un correo no se puede linkear con css, tienes que poner esos estilos de forma directa en el html

Aqui se explica eso:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoCBBW7DTiU

Answer (score 0):

No se si has cambiado cosas desde que preguntaste, pero ahora viendo el código fuente me he fijado en que le das estilos a elementos con id `#top` y `#logo`, pero no hay ningún elemento con alguno de esos id. Si solo algunos de los estilos no se aplican puede que ese sea el error.